# Android - Shortname to Unicode from Emojione doesn't work

Tags: android, unicode

First of all, I don't know whether I should ask this here or in the repo, but as I saw other questions for other libraries like.. Picasso, so here goes :

I'm trying to implement Emojione into my Android app. I've downloaded a small static class to convert all short name to unicode from [Emojione Github Repo](https://github.com/Ranks/emojione/tree/master/lib/android/com/emojione).

The problem is, when I try to use it to convert :smile: to unicode..

`Emojione.shortnameToUnicode(postMessageText, true); // postMessageText is ":smile:"`

It always return.. A square, as if it failed to convert. I tried other short names too like :smiley:, :grinning:, but they also failed. :(something): is really a short name right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is actually in front of my eyes all the time. It really did convert to unicode but, I might be wrong here, in a font unsupported by Android. So I tried using `SpannableStringBuilder` to span the emoji part to use `emojione-android.ttf`

Here's how :

```
int firstEq = sb.length();
Typeface font = FontCache.getTypeface("emojione-android.ttf", context);
String convertPart = Emojione.shortnameToUnicode(part, true);
sb.append(convertPart + " ");
int lastEq = sb.length();
sb.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("", font), firstEq, lastEq, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

And that's how I got the `TextView` to show emojis.. Just use the font!

Comment: it works fine, but i got an error, spaces are removed when using setSpan and some smartphones shows an error like "Native typeface can not be made",  one question, did you built your own emojione keyboard just to replace the native emoji on Android? Thank you

Comment: @Jonatan Hmm in my experience, setSpan doesn't remove my space.. No, I didn't build my own emojione keyboard, I kind of rely on stock keyboard's emoji functions :D